# Solution to the differential equation $\frac{1}{2}\dot K-K^2+K=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The solution the differential equation $\frac{1}{2}\dot K-K^2+K=0$ is given in the picture below

**Picture**

> [image]

**My solution**

> $\frac{\mathrm{d} K}{2(K^2-K)}=\mathrm{d} t$ and
>   $\frac{1}{K^2-K}=\frac{-1}{K}+\frac{1}{K-1}$ so
>
> $$-\ln|K| +\ln|K-1|=2t+T$$
>
> so
>
> $$\ln \frac{|K-1|}{|K|}=2t+T$$
>
> so
>
> $$\frac{|K-1|}{|K|}=e^{2t+T}$$

**Question**

> **How is the solution $$K=\frac{e^{T-t}}{e^{T-t}+e^{t-T}}$$ to the differential equation deduced?**

*P.s. Source of the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7bf4.png) and unfortunately [privately](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-2.3148/luennot/Mat-2_3148_luento_5_2.pdf).*

Comment: After your second "so", you are removing an absolute value, so you assume $|K|>1$. If instead $|K|<1$, you need to change sign.

Comment: Also, I am a bit confused: What does $T$ represent in the original problem? I think your usage of $T$ and the problem's usage of $T$ is a bit different, which might be another source of the error.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: didn't you mean $K > 1$ and $K < 1$?

Comment: @Braindead They are certainly of opposite sign, which is legal since $T$ is any constant, but confusing. rubik, there is nowhere an asumption that $K$ is positive?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Excellent point! It is a mistake -- wait I haven't considered absolute values deeply enough probably -- there is no restriction for K. $T$ is a constant in **My Solution**.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I could consider a bit simpler problem where $K>1$ to get rid of the absolute values. Even then the solution in **My solution** does not match the given solution, why?

Comment: Does the given solution assume $K>1$ and the same sign on $T$? (if you change $T$ in $-T$, the solution is mostly the same) I think these two points explain the differences you see.

Comment: @rubik I just understood your comment, you are right of course :-) And to complete the cases, if $K=1$ for some $t$, then $K=1$ for all $t$ (from uniqueness of local solution, and the fact that $K(t)=1$ is a solution)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I believe $T$ in the solution is also off by a factor of 2.

Comment: The constant $T$ is the value of $t$ that makes $K = 1/2$. Being as such, the first line of your derivation, you should have $2t - 2T$ rather than $2t + T$. If you want to just use an arbitrary constant,you should write $2t + C$, then figure out what $C$ should be in terms of $T$. (And I can tell you that $C$ will come out to be $-2T$.